# No horizontal navigation showing on Magento custom theme

Tags: magento

I have decided to sit down and build my first custom theme in Magento and I'm using this tutorial: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/magento-for-designers-part-4/

However I cant for the life of me find a way to include horizontal navigation (Home | Shop | Contact etc.) along the top of my website!

I tried all the suggestions I could find including placing everything in the root category and enabling all cats in the navigation.. refreshing the cache etc.

I've been working at this for hours now and been searching everywhere for an answer. I've pretty much followed the tutorial step by step but I can't see any way to enable the Nav - can someone please point me in the right direction with this?

(I'm kind of assuming Magento have a way to do this to add categories automatically - I'm aware I could hard code the navigation bar but I'm trying to avoid this.)

Comment: show us the code you've done and explain the problem/error it gives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the screenshot on the tutorial, it doesn't actually have the menu anyway.

I'd recommend you check out leveluptuts magento theming tutorials, who actually take the base theme and manipulates it into the desired theme. I think you'll have much more luck that way as most of the templates and layout files are already built.

http://leveluptuts.com/tutorials/magento-community-tutorials/25-theming-magento-1-intro-theming

For the top menu, the default theme pages call the "header.phtml" template for the header block (app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/header.phtml), which in turns calls the "topmenu.phtml" template (app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/topmenu.phtml) where the menu code is.

The layout files is page.xml

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for this! :) I'm still having issues calling the topMenu for some reason but I'm sure I'll be able to figure it out with the info you've provided.